# Stats for testing a renderer

Tags: metrics

I've been writing an OpenGL renderer as a learning process for the past few weeks. Now I wanted to test my renderer against some known numbers, for instance:

- How many vertices/tris should it be able to render at 60 fps (rough estimate?)
- How many draw calls before it is expected to drops the fps?
- etc?

This is all assuming simple shaders (one that outputs a single texture) and a reasonable video card (3~4 yrs old).

Comment: Good question, I would try to compare it to the best known engines out there in hope for some data. If you find something interesting be sure to share.

Comment: The question doesn't say, but I'm assuming you're asking for a method to capture those stats?

Comment: @Anko well, not really. I know how many vertices I have in a given scene and the fps too. I want to know whats the usual amount of data a renderer is suposed to be able to render without framerate loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following wondra's advice, I decided to check some engines, this is what I found:

**Unity 3D** (http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OptimizingGraphicsPerformance.html)

- Draw Calls: "several thousand" (PC) and "several hundred" (Mobile)
- Vertices: "not more than a 100 thousand" (Mobile) and "not more than several million" (PC)

**jMonkeyEngine** (http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/forum/topic/a-polygon-limit/)

- Vertices (Developer answer): " if you want [...] to run on low hardwares [...] shouldn’t have more that 100k polygons" (PC), "30k poly" (Android)
- Triangles (User): Renders 5m triangles at 200 fps

**Torque 3D** (http://www.garagegames.com/community/forums/viewthread/134244)

- Vertices: Around 3 million.

---

To be honest it was a bit hard to find even this information, I couldn't find anything for Ogre3D or UDK. Even what I found is always surounded by "it depends". So I guess the final answer really is "it depends" but 5m vertices/500 draw calls sound like reasonable numbers to aim for.

I'm leaving the question open because someone else might have better input than this.